# How to list the files inside directory and sub directories?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a directory and in that there are sub-directories that have text files,now i want to list all the .txt files in the sub-directories with path. how to do this?

Comment: `ls -l yourdir/*.txt` for example

Comment: @fedorqui: that will not list *.txt files in sub-directories.

Comment: You are right @cdarke, I missed the sub-directory step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
find / -type f -name \*.txt
```

It will give you all .txt files in '/' directory.

Comment: For more reference, please read about find command: http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_find.htm

Answer (score 2):

Use find command

```
find /where/to/search -name "*.txt" -type f
```

That will list only files ending .txt. Using -type f it won't list directory even if it's name happens to end with .txt.

Answer (score 1):

Several ways:

```
echo directory_name/*/*.txt
```

is probably the most efficient: `echo` is a shell built-in, and the * expansion is done by `bash`. If you need more power, use `ls` instead of `echo`

Comment: He might want to loop through them as well... `for f in /etc/*; do echo $f; done`

Answer (score 0):

Try This One : `tree -R | grep ".txt"`

Comment: tree is to list in tree like format and it is not installed by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -R path_of_your_directory | grep "\.txt$"
```

Example:

```
ls -R /tmp | grep "\.txt$"
```